# How to deserialise json data from the World of Warcraft auction API using Json.NET

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization, world-of-warcraft

Here is an example snippet of the json data that the API returns:

```
{
"realm":{"name":"Molten Core","slug":"molten-core"},
"auctions":{"auctions":[
    {"auc":1880591075,"item":109128,"owner":"Leagra","ownerRealm":"Azjol-Nerub","bid":858600,"buyout":900000,"quantity":100,"timeLeft":"VERY_LONG","rand":0,"seed":0,"context":0},
    {"auc":1879726534,"item":43115,"owner":"Nêwt","ownerRealm":"Azjol-Nerub","bid":5120000,"buyout":5120000,"quantity":16,"timeLeft":"VERY_LONG","rand":0,"seed":835268864,"context":0}]}
}
```

*(Though obviously with real data there's thousands of auctions.)*

I'm looking to deserialise this, ignoring the realm data and just putting the auctions into a nice clean `List<WowAuction>` object, with `WowAuction` being:

```
public class WowAuction
{
      public long auc { get; set; }
      public long item { get; set; }
      public long bid { get; set; }
      public long buyout { get; set; }
}
```

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around how I would do this, the json the API returns seems rather messy to me (though admittedly I haven't worked with json before).

As far as I can tell, there's a collection called "auctions", inside of that is a single field also called "auctions" which is a table, that table then contains rows of auction data. How would I deserialise this?

Comment: Mimic the type structure in your model. Create a few extra classes and you're done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways you could do that but the simple way is to create a domain object with the same structure as your JSON:

```
public class WoWAuctionResponse {
    public WoWRealmInfo Realm {get; set;}
    public WoWAuctionsBody Auctions {get; set;}
}

public class WoWAuctionsBody {
   public List<WoWAuction> Auctions {get; set;}
}

// ...

JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WoWAuctionResponse>(json);
```

Comment: Thanks, seems simple now. I guess my problem was mostly disagreeing with their choice of data formatting and assuming there must be a cleaner way I couldn't think of.

Answer (score 1):

To extend @slvnperron's answer.

First, build your classes. I recommend to use a tool like [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/).

```
    public class Realm
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string slug { get; set; }
    }

    public class Auction
    {
        public int auc { get; set; }
        public int item { get; set; }
        public string owner { get; set; }
        public string ownerRealm { get; set; }
        public int bid { get; set; }
        public int buyout { get; set; }
        public int quantity { get; set; }
        public string timeLeft { get; set; }
        public int rand { get; set; }
        public int seed { get; set; }
        public int context { get; set; }
    }

    public class Auctions
    {
        public List<Auction> auctions { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public Realm realm { get; set; }
        public Auctions auctions { get; set; }
    }
```

Second, parse your json. i recommend to use a tool like [Json.net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json). You can install it with nuget.

```
    public static void Main()
    {
        string json = @"{here your json}";
        RootObject m = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
        Console.WriteLine(m.realm.name.Trim());
    }
```

here our output will be :

```
Molten Core
```

Working example on [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/EowAqz).

Answer (score 1):

Have your domain model this way and deserialize your data.

```
internal class WowAuction
{

    [JsonProperty("realm")]
    public Realm Realm { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("auctions")]
    public Auctions Auctions { get; set; }
}


internal class Realm
{

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("slug")]
    public string Slug { get; set; }
}

internal class Auctions
{

    [JsonProperty("auctions")]
    public Auction[] Auctions { get; set; }
}

internal class Auction
{

    [JsonProperty("auc")]
    public int Auc { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("item")]
    public int Item { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("owner")]
    public string Owner { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("ownerRealm")]
    public string OwnerRealm { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("bid")]
    public int Bid { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("buyout")]
    public int Buyout { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("quantity")]
    public int Quantity { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("timeLeft")]
    public string TimeLeft { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("rand")]
    public int Rand { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("seed")]
    public int Seed { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("context")]
    public int Context { get; set; }
}
```

Later you can have following statement to deserialize your data

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WowAuction>(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Things have changed a bit since this question was originally asked.  The [World of Warcraft APIs](https://develop.battle.net/documentation/world-of-warcraft) now include Game Data and Profile APIs.  As the other answers here describe, you can create model classes and use [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) or a similar library to handle the deserialization.  There are also NuGet packages like the [Argent Pony Warcraft Client](https://github.com/blizzard-net/warcraft) or the [BattleMuffin Blizzard API Client](https://gitlab.com/themuffinman/BattleMuffin) that have already defined model classes and handle the deserialization for you.

An example with the [ArgentPonyWarcraftClient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ArgentPonyWarcraftClient/) NuGet package follows.  It displays a subset of the information available for each auction.

```
string clientId = "CLIENT-ID-GOES-HERE";
string clientSecret = "CLIENT-SECRET-GOES-HERE";

int connectedRealmId = 1146;

IAuctionHouseApi warcraftClient = new WarcraftClient(
    clientId: clientId,
    clientSecret: clientSecret,
    region: Region.US,
    locale: Locale.en_US);

RequestResult<AuctionsIndex> result = await warcraftClient.GetAuctionsAsync(connectedRealmId, "dynamic-us");

if (result.Success)
{
    AuctionsIndex auctions = result.Value;

    foreach(Auction auction in auctions.Auctions)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{auction.Id}: Item ID: {auction.Item.Id} Quantity: {auction.Quantity}");
    }
}
```